# CSS - Android Lollipop Tap & Hold Background Style

Tags: css

**SOLUTION:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/df5fnxso/) (Thanks to Josiah)

**UPDATE:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/gdb6hddq/6/) (Thanks to GaneshBhosale)

I'm trying to style a button so that when the user hovers it, its background is a circle that grows like the one you can see in the animation below.
I've made some tests but i don't have any working Fiddle.
Anyone knows how to do it?

HTML

```
<figure>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/nature/1" alt="" />
  <figcaption class="circle">Oh, la belle image!</figcaption>  </a>
</figure>
<figure>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/nature/1" alt="" />
  <figcaption class="star">Oh, la belle image!</figcaption>  </a>
</figure>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50%,50%,10%);
  clip-path: circle(50%,50%,10%);
}
a:hover .circle,
a:focus .circle {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50%,50%,75%);
  clip-path: circle(50%,50%,75%);
}

.star {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 38%, 58% 62%, 38% 47%, 62% 47%, 42% 62%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 40%, 58% 60%, 40% 47%, 60% 47%, 42% 60%);
}
a:hover .star,
a:focus .star {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% -100%, 180% 200%, -100% 0%, 200% 0%, -80% 200%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% -100%, 180% 200%, -100% 0%, 200% 0%, -80% 200%);
}

figcaption {

  position: absolute;

  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  transition: -webkit-clip-path .3s;

}

/*cosmetics*/
figure {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
figcaption {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  color: yellowgreen;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
html {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT: IT CAN ALSO BE A LINK, A LI ITEM OR A DIV**

Thank you and thanks to AndroidPolice for the GIF!

[image: Animation]

Comment: Can you still post your code attempts?

Comment: I based on http://codepen.io/iamvdo/pen/EIjLa but this doesn't work sometimes and it doesn't animate.
Also, i want the background to have that effect and not the foreground

Comment: I especially like [this example](http://codepen.io/dwijitsolutions/pen/myrvJW). It uses JS, but not a lot. Only to create an overlay layer. Love it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rdoyle720 sort of had the right idea, and using an image is definitely the easiest way to do this. However, I would suggest using two containers, a parent and the "circle". You center the circle, set `no-repeat`, and make it's `background-size` 0. Then, on parent `:hover` or `:active` (I did hover), you set the "circle" background-size to something large.

Example:

```css
#parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#circle {
    background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .3s ease-in;
}

#parent:hover #circle {
    background-size: 600px 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"> <div id="circle"> </div> </div>
```

You could use a different circle color if you want. Also, I would suggest SVG graphics, so the scaling looks smooth. Otherwise your edges will become choppy.

For an example using `:active` see this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4bz0spx/1/)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I ended up with :)
http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/kxsgk0w7/

Answer (score 4):

This is a good script for same purpose:

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.nexus');
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].onmousedown = function(e) {

    var x = (e.offsetX == undefined) ? e.layerX : e.offsetX;
    var y = (e.offsetY == undefined) ? e.layerY : e.offsetY;
    var effect = document.createElement('div');
    effect.className = 'effect';
    effect.style.top = y + 'px';
    effect.style.left = x + 'px';
    e.srcElement.appendChild(effect);
    setTimeout(function() {
      e.srcElement.removeChild(effect);
    }, 1100);
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes clickeffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes clickeffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

.nexus {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #838383;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nexus:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
}

a.nexus{
  height: 37px;
  padding: 7px 0px;
}
button.nexus{

}

.effect {
  margin: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transform: scale(0);
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: clickeffect 1s ease;
  -webkit-animation: clickeffect 1s ease;
}

.nexus.grey {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #838383;
}

.nexus.red {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #EA7878;
}

.nexus.green {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #77CA72;
}
```

```html
<br>
<center>
  <h2>Click on link to see effect</h2>
  <button class="nexus grey">Button 1</button><br><br>
  <button class="nexus red">Button 2</button><br><br>
  <a href="http://dwijitsolutions.com" class="nexus green" target="_blank">Anchor 1</a><br>
</center>
```

Reference document:
http://dwij.in/nuggets/animated-button-with-material-design-like-android-lollipop.html

Comment: Your base is good but I improved it further. I'm using Maxthon as primary browser and your snippet isn't working here (Transform scale is not supported). Check here for a fixed version that uses width and margins instead of scale http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/gdb6hddq/3/

Comment: EDIT: It looks like the "fix" breaks Google Chrome. I'm working on a css code that is correctly displayed on all (or most) browsers.

Comment: UPDATE: I forgot to remove some transform voices, this new update works on Chrome too, and I'll now test the other browsers.
(http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/gdb6hddq/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I was just experimenting with something like this. Create a circle background, named circle.png.

```
.tap {
    background: url(circle.png) center center no-repeat; 
    background-size: 0 0;
    transition: .5s;
}
.tap:active {
    background-size: 2500px 2500px;
}
HTML:
<a href="#" class="tap">test</a>
```

Not perfect, but should give you a start.

Comment: It doesn't even animate for me...looks like transition isn't working

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and Firefox...what browser are you testing in?